# Cannot Run/Debug Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I have created a simple Rails application from File -> New -> Rails Project.
When I click on App Explorer and then on the blue gear wheel and then on Run Server or Debug Server, nothing happens.
But I can start WEBrick manually by typing "rails server" at the Terminal. I don't mind starting my Rails app with this command instead of clicking on Run Server. But the problem is that i don't know how to debug my Rails apps other than clicking on Debug Server.

Edit: My Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p353 [x64-mingw32]
The ruby-debug-ide gem is also installed.

Comment: How are your automated tests? They are incredibly more important than debugging. (Disclaimer: I debug all the time. The automated tests also make that easy...)

Comment: As I said I created just a plane rails skeleton so there are no automated tests yet. What have automated tests to do with debugging? I just want to use the  debugger.

Comment: Watch out for project folder structure. I had similar issue and resolved it. Here is my reply for a similar kindof problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/23504733/2119981