# How do I get Eclipse Debug Server to debug rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, debugging

I have a simple rails app that runs in Eclipse Juno when I use the command line 'rails server' to launch.
I now need to debug in the eclipse ide and set breakpoints, and I can't figure out how to run the server withing eclipse using either 'Run Server', 'Debug Server', 'Run As', or 'Debug As'.  Nothing happens, no output to the Console, nothing.

My gemlist has:
Using debugger-linecache (1.2.0)/
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.2)/
Using debugger (1.6.6)

I ran bundle install and 'gem install debugger' successfully.
I have Ruby 1.93, Rails 3.2.17
Windows 7.
Restarted.

I have an eclipse environment configured on my MAC, with the debugger, but I can't find the missing piece for the Windows setup.

Thanks very much,

Anne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar issue with my eclipse + aptana plugin. When I select 'debug/run server', nothing happened.

The issue was with the project structure. In my case, I had an empty rails project (testProject) in eclipse and imported my rails application from file system (railsApp). So, the project explorer, had hierarchy as

testProject -> railsApp -> app, config, etc..

But, In order to make the debugging work, I had to have my project hierarchy as railsApp -> app, config, etc..

Todo that, In a fresh eclipse, import existing folder as a new project with 'rails project' as a default perspective. Then debugging works fine.

Cheers !

Comment: Thanks very much.  I did eventually get it working, but I'm not sure exactly how.  I just checked my directory structure and it does have the hierarchy described above.